# Creating Different Builds in UWP

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I am trying to create different builds for my UWP project in Visual Studio. I essentially want to do something similar to creating build variants in Android Studio but have found no good resources on how to do that for my UWP app. Is there anyway for me to have different build variants so that at build time I am able to set a URL to different values based on which build is chosen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what type of changes you have in your build variant?

Comment: I only want to add different configurations regarding which API_URL to target per build environment, I was able to do this through different run-time configurations

Comment: Better to have some flag/enum and create one property which will set the APP_URL to an appropriate value, when you want to build your package just update the enum so that appropriate URL will be fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using the [Configuration Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to create the various build configurations that you want.  You might start in Visual Studio by clicking on Build->Configuration Manager, and then clicking on either the "Active solution configuration" dropdown, or the "Active Solution platforms" dropdown (depending on what you are trying to do), and selecting "New".

Then, right click on you project and choose "Properties".  Navigate to "Build", and change the "Conditional Compilation symbols" to define different symbols for different build Configurations.  For example, you might add one called "BUILD_1" for your first configuration, then switch configurations, and add a new symbol called "BUILD_2" for your second configuration.

Then, in your code, you can do something like this:

```
#if BUILD_1
String myUrl = "http://google.com"
#elif BUILD_2
String myUrl = "http://apple.com"
#else
String myUrl = "http://microsoft.com"
#endif
```

You might want to first read the Microsoft docs on [Configuration Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), as there is some trickiness there in making sure you setup your new configuration(s) similar to your old configuration(s).

Comment: This is how I solved my problem. I definitely agree that the Configuration Manager had some intricacies that were a little difficult. I marked your answer as correct for other people to see this.